# Blackberry 10 native simple app to open url

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

I'm trying to write a simple app to open a url, which works, but only once?

```
#include <bps/bps.h>
#include <bps/navigator_invoke.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    bps_initialize();

    navigator_invoke_invocation_t *invoke = NULL;
    navigator_invoke_invocation_create(&invoke);

    navigator_invoke_invocation_set_target(invoke, "sys.browser");
    navigator_invoke_invocation_set_action(invoke, "bb.action.OPEN");
    navigator_invoke_invocation_set_uri(invoke, "http://www.stackoverflow.com");

    navigator_invoke_invocation_send(invoke);
    navigator_invoke_invocation_destroy(invoke);

    bps_shutdown();

    return 0;
}
```

Can't really get any simpler right? When I run it, it opens and browses to StackOverflow, but if I close the browser and open it again, it doesn't really do anything, certainly doesn't open the browser again.... What am I doing wrong here? (new to BB/BB10)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a video [on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RLHR6JCHEaA), it works as it should. And [here is Github with source](https://gist.github.com/40/3752815). It is a **cascades** solution, so I hope it will be ok for you.

Another way is to just put this in:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com",QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

Even though this methods both work (tested!), I suggest you instead use WebView, and refresh/redirect it immediately. This way your website will stay open within your application.

Comment: Cascades code cannot be called from a core native app cause it doesn't use Qmake, you should've provided an alternative that uses just BPS.

Comment: I told him it's a cascades app. For his purpose, it doesn't really make much of a difference what he uses